# saving data foreach passed value outside using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i have this multiple select dropdown in my tax year the data in select dropdown are

```
2011-2012
2012-2013
2013-2014
2014-2015
2015-2016
2016-2017
2017-2018
```

the select dropdown multiple works well when passed into the controller in laravel. Now my problem is when the taxes is being passed then i added a foreach loop for my select dropdown multiple it works fine. but upon saving only one data saved because the save function is outside in foreach. How will i able to passed the foreach data then saved outside the foreach loop. Here is my code below

```
$taxes = $request->get('taxYear');

foreach($taxes as $key=>$tax) {
    $mulTax = $tax.",";     
}

exit;

$case = new Opp([
    'code'=>$uNum,
    'client_id'=>$cName_0,
    'contacts'=>$cName,
    'tax_year'=>$mulTax,
    'owner'=>$owner,
]);

$case->save();
$retId = $case->id;
Response::json(['success' => true,'id' => $retId], 200); 

Session::flash('caseCreated', 'Successfully created cases');
return redirect('cases/create');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used like that

> used concating operator

```
$mulTax = "";
foreach($taxes as $key=>$tax){
            $mulTax .= $tax.",";
 }


        $case = new Opp([
            'code'=>$uNum,
            'client_id'=>$cName_0,
            'contacts'=>$cName,
            'tax_year'=> rtrim($mulTax,',');,   //remove last comma(,) from string 
            'owner'=>$owner,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $taxes = $request->get('taxYear');

    $mulTax = '';

    foreach($taxes as $key=>$tax){
        $mulTax = $mulTax . $tax.",";

    }

    exit;

    $case = new Opp([
        'code'=>$uNum,
        'client_id'=>$cName_0,
        'contacts'=>$cName,
        'tax_year'=>$mulTax,
        'owner'=>$owner,
    ]);

    $case->save();
    $retId = $case->id;
    Response::json(['success' => true,'id' => $retId], 200); 

    Session::flash('caseCreated', 'Successfully created cases');
    return redirect('cases/create');
```

Comment: Why did you change the accepted answer? You said it worked with the above?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the foreach for this, use implode function instead

```
$taxes = $request->get('taxYear');
$taxes = implode(",", $taxes);

$case = new Opp([
    'code'=>$uNum,
    'client_id'=>$cName_0,
    'contacts'=>$cName,
    'tax_year'=>$taxes,
    'owner'=>$owner,
]);
```